# Using VIM to make acronyms?

Tags: vim

I have a file with lot of full names like ....

```
Light Machine Gun
Statistical Analysis System
etc
```

I want to capture the first character of every word in a line and want to make an acronym. For example Light Machine Gun would be LMG etc. I want to do it in VI editor record it as a macro and run it over the entire file.If anyone can help me that would be great? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming one name per line and that the words are space separated, the following works:

```
%s/\(\w\)\w*\ */\1/g
```

If you also want to capitalize each letter, add an up-case flag (`\u`):

```
%s/\(\w\)\w* */\u\1/g
```

The "very magic" version (see `:help /magic`):

```
%s/\v(\w)\w*\s*/\u\1/g
```

Comment: Have you tried this? It doesn't work. But this does: `%s/\(\w\)\w*\s*/\1/g`.

Comment: @glts: I did, but I copied the wrong bit when posting. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know why `%s/\(\w\)\w*\s+/\1/g` does not work? This should match multiple whitespaces, right? (I am new to vim regex).

Comment: @oyenamit: the `+` quantifier should also be escaped (`\+`), unless you're using "very magic" (see `:help /magic`), in which case it becomes: `%s/\v(\w)\w*\s+/\u\1/g`; but you don't want `+` here because it will fail to match the end of line, so it should be: `%s/\v(\w)\w*\s*/\u\1/g`.

Comment: Inspired by all of you, i tried to use a non greedy char(?)  %s/\v(.)(\w+) ?/\1/g --- This also worked for me. Thanks again for your efforts

Answer (score 3):

Vim can define acronyms, called abbreviations, say you want

```
Light Machine Gun Statistical Analysis System -> LMGSAS
```

Just enter:

```
:ab LMGSAS Light Machine Gun Statistical Analysis System
```

And whenever you type LMGSAS it will substitute it for you.

Use `:ab` to list out all abbreviations, `una xxxxx` to unabbreviate something. And finally `abc` clears everything.

Edit: I misunderstood your question, if your trying to go, words -> abbreviations, then the regex `s/\(\w\)\w*\s*/\1/g` suggested by Thor works fine.

Comment: It does not answer the question directly but it is useful to know if you want to work the other way round.

Comment: I edited to include an actual way to solve the question, apparently people found this answer useful though so i'll leave it